# Why is my Flutter app not building after I add an import statement, and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: flutter, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

I have been trying to set a widget from another file (app.dart) in my flutter project as "home: " in main.dart in my project. The project builds and runs until I add the import statement at the top, and then I get several errors, the last of which is "Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1". I'm new to Flutter, but from everything I've read the import statement should work just fine.

The file structure is this:

- lib/

  - app/

    - app.dart
  - main.dart

I have tried creating a temporary project (called temp_project), adding the additional files from my other project, and leaving main.dart entirely default. The project builds just fine until I add the import statement for app.dart.

What's also weird is that app.dart has imports for other files, and the project builds just fine when I only comment out the imports in main.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp_project/app/app.dart'; // this is the import that is causing the errors

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

app.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp_project/chat/chat.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Codename: Holy Grounds',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0,
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (_, child) => _Unfocus(child: child!),
      home: const ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class _Unfocus extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Unfocus({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what did you write in app.dart?

Comment: see updates to the question for app.dart contents. sorry, forgot to include that the first time

Comment: The import should work as you wrote it. Are you sure the package name is the right one ? Corresponding to your project name. If nothing is working try restarting the IDE, sometimes it has issues loading dependencies